# How to make a custom managed property searchable

Tags: search, enterprise-search, user-profile-property

I have added a new property "Initials" to my User Profile Synchronization Service and mapped it to a property from AD. That works and the property gets properly imported into user's profiles. I have even managed to successfully show it in search results, however I still cannot search for it specifically.

For example, if I type in "Initials:RSA" my name comes up in search. [image]

That's great but I'd like to just be able to type "RSA" and see the same result.

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the user profile property, did you set it as Indexed? If not search won't pick it up no matter how you configure the Managed Property. BTW, Alias works in conjuntion with people search to equate the property to a person, but you also need to add the property to the RankingWeightName managed property to get it all to work correctly if that is the desired behavior. http://www.ableblue.com/blog/archive/2011/03/15/sharepoint-people-search-and-alias-fields/

You also need to do a full profile crawl after you make these changes.

Comment: Thank you Matthew! Adding the property to the RankingWeightName (i had it set to Indexed and as an Alias before) solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add new Managed property to Search Schema in Search Service Application settings. Map this property to People:Initials crawled property and then start a full crawl.

Or, as a second option, you can try to set "Alias" checkbox in your "Initials" property settings.

Comment: From the post, I get the feeling that the managed property has been created and configured, but it is not free text searchable.

Comment: Hmm, I don't get it from post. Then maybe "Query" is enabled in managed property settings? From description of this checkbox it does exactly that is described in the post.